# simple HTML form not working?

Tags: html, forms

I have really basic problem but cant seem to find problem. I have a simple HTML form which i cant get to work (cant even go to google.com), so i was wondering if you can see any obvious mistake i am missing here.

```
<form action="www.google.hr" id="questionForm" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Naputci za studente:</legend>       
                        <textarea name="help" id="help"><?php print($result['Help']); ?></textarea><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="create"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Thank you all for your help, unfortuneantly nothing helped resolve this issue so it must be something else thats bothering this part of code. Once again, I appriciate all your help.

Edit:

I was looking through google chrome developer tools and it seems that it doesnt "read" form line, anyway i have a screenshot so here it is?

[image: No <form> line???]

Comment: Seems to be working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2Du/)

Comment: Put a `http://` in front of the url in your action.

Comment: is it possible that something else is interfering with this form, or this form should work for itself?

Answer (score 3):

Try intead of `action="www.google.hr"` to do `action="http://www.google.hr"` so:

```
<form action="http://www.google.hr" id="questionForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Naputci za studente:</legend>       
        <textarea name="help" id="help"><?php print($result['Help']); ?></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="create"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As patrick stated in his answer, a GET can be applied too, instead of POST, this will take all the values and literally places them inside the URL.

If i changed this form to GET it will send this url:

```
https://www.google.hr/?help=%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cb%3ENotice%3C%2Fb%3E%3A++Undefined+variable%3A+result+in+%3Cb%3EC%3A%5Ccode%5COpdrachten+Bram%5CPHPStorm%5CKeyword+Density+Tool%5Cretrieve_url.php%3C%2Fb%3E+on+line+%3Cb%3E87%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0D%0A
```

Anyway, if i change the action attribute to `something.php` for example. And hit the submit button it goes directly to something.php, wheter it's post or get. So your form is correctly made. I think you should look somewhere else in your code.

Comment: still refreshes same page :/, anyway its obviously something else thats bothering this form. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @user2740217 Hmm, when I add it to my scripty and hit submit, it takes me to google.hr and says something about invalid post values. But it most certainly takes me to google.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- You should prefix your url with `http://`;
- Google does not accept cross-domain posts. Try `get`:

  ```
  <form action="http://www.google.com/" id="questionForm" method="get">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Naputci za studente:</legend>       
          <textarea name="q" id="q"></textarea><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Update" id="create"/>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  ```

Test this on a local file, since jsfiddle will block this kind of requests.

Comment: Hey patrick, this code works but it's not entirely the point that it needs to work with google. He basically said that it didn't do anything so he tried google as action and it didn't send him there. So basically the http:// was enough for that part of the problem =]